# The explanation of the word phrase "understudy execution"

Tags: word-meaning

I am translating one text about pedagogy and I have there such a sentence:

> Understudy execution, in any case, is additionally dependent upon educator expertise and level  of exertion or inspiration.

Could you please explain what "understudy execution" means here?

Comment: It is technical language, and even though I'm quite familar with the jargon of education, this is incomprehensible to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of pedagogy (education), an understudy (noun), Google tells me, is a student who is 'understudying', that is, performing badly. The 'execution' of that student seems to be the student's performance.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I have plenty of such misleading points in this text. I will be really grateful to you if you will help me with them!